# do_package() before do_compile() possible?

Tags: bitbake

Is it possible to have `do_package()` before `do_compile()` in a bitbake recipe?
In this case, binaries from the previous bitbake run would be deployed. Would bitbake have warning about this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure if it is possible to change the order of some built-in tasks, but given your sentence "in this case, binaries from the previous bitbake run would be deployed", I think it is not the proper way to archive that.

Yocto/Bitbake supports incremental build and package dependencies so that if a local artifact is still valid it won't be rebuild.

In Yocto, you can also setup a shared folder (on a server) to store build artifacts so that even when building "from scratch" from a known state, will actually results in downloading the artifacts instead of building them.
You can look at https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#shared-state-cache to get more info on that.

Note: if you want/need to try it anyway, maybe adding a custom task using `add task custompackage before do_compile` would be a way to investigate it.
Otherwise, to use built-in names, I would try to `deltask` those, and recreate them with custom ordering, but once again, that looks risky to me.